# How to get multiple rows by position with a single query?

Tags: android, sqlite

I can get a single row by position with offset and limit. But I have an array of **positions** and I want to get *rows from that positions*.

Is there any way to get these rows with a **single query** without a for loop?

**Note:** The id is unknown to me. Is my case positions are not the ids.

**Why I Need This:**

```
SELECT question_id FROM questions where question_bank_id in (1, 3) ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5
```

The above query returns 5 random values from 1 and 3. But I need 5 rows from 1 and 5 rows from 5. I can achieve this with a loop. But my table size is large.

So I am finding an alternative to achieve this efficiently. That's why I am thinking to generate random integers first and then fetch values from that positions.

Comment: please explain in brief :)

Comment: I do not want to get rows by their ids. I want to fetch rows by the row positions. @Exigente05

Comment: Then, what is the logic to get by position? Any column value or something you are maintaining, right?

Comment: If your data is fixed/static then you should know the ids, if not (Ex., any row can be deleted, or new can be added) what will you do by position? There should be a column value using which you will fetch data or for fixed data you should fetch by ids (for fixed data IDs could represent your position.

Comment: My table is not static. Suppose my table ids starts from 200 or whatever I don't know. Now I am generating 4 random integers as (2, 8, 9, 5). Now I want the rows from position 2, 8, 9 and 5. So I cannot get the rows with IDs. I need them by position. Hope you understand now. @Exigente05

Comment: You can generate pseudo ids on the fly (in either sql or your application code) and use that to return the rows at those 'positions'. For further assistance, See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Exigente05 as you understood it is not a duplicate question as you mentioned, can you pease remove that comment saying its duplicate? TIA

Comment: Yes, sure. Removed.

Comment: If it's x random rows that you want then you could use SQLite's **random** function e.g.`SELECT * FROM yourtable ORDER BY random() LIMIT 4`. The you can use a single simple query.

Comment: @MikeT Thanks Mike. I Tried this and it does not fulfill my requirements, so I was looking for other solutions.

`SELECT question_id FROM questions where question_bank_id in (1, 3) ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5`

this returns 5 random rows from 1 and 3. But I need 5 rows from 1 and 5 rows from 3.  I can achieve this with a loop but I dont know how efficient this is. So I was thinking generating the positions first and then fetch those rows.

Answer (score 2):

To get a single row, you would use a query like this:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1 OFFSET ?;
```

To get multiple rows, combine multiple queries:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1 OFFSET ?
UNION ALL
SELECT ... FROM ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1 OFFSET ?
UNION ALL
SELECT ... FROM ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1 OFFSET ?
...
```

You need a for loop to construct this query, so executing multiple queries might be easier.

Comment: Thank you CL. I think I have to use the random function. Your solution would also work. But can you tell which one is more efficient?

Comment: If you need five questions each from two banks, then you should combine two ORDER BY random() LIMIT 5 queries.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTICE**: this answer refers to mySQL as per original question

I don't know if it counts for you as a single query but it is probably as close as you will get:

```
SET @row_num = 0;

SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            @row_num := @row_num + 1 AS row_number, 
            t.id
       FROM 
           your_table AS t 
       ORDER BY 
           t.id) AS q
WHERE
    q.row_number IN (3, 5);
```

I assume that you wanted position by it's order and not bu unique id key. Above query creates temporary row_number which than could be used to select as many positions as you want.

Please notice that rows selection will depend on what field will be in `ORDER BY` - it doesn't have to be id (primary key).

Comment: @CL.: Tags were changed - before they contained mysql and even the title was stating that it refers to mysql

Comment: @StormoPL Thank you for the answer. I am really sorry that I put the tag and question  as mysql. I thought I could find alternative for sqlite. But now I see that I cannot execute it on sqlite.

Comment: @SajidAnam: No problem mate. I will still leave this answer in case someone was looking for solution of the same problem like yours but in mySQL

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried (see below) this but you could perhaps utilise a **MergeCursor**.

That is create an array of Cursors for the required banks and then use them to create a **MergeCursor** and then use that.

Along the lines of :-

```
String sqlbank1 = 
    "SELECT question_id FROM questions WHERE question_bank_id = 1 ORDER BY random() LIMIT 5";
String sqlbank2 = 
    "SELECT question_id FROM questions WHERE question_bank_id = 3 ORDER BY random() LIMIT 5";
Cursor[] cursors = new Cursor[]{db.rawQuery(sqlbank1),db.rawQuery(sqlbank2)};
Cursor questions = new MergeCursor(cursors);
// or MergeCursor questions = new MergCursor(cursors);
```

Note! not tested so the code is *in principle*. You should also close the cursors (I haven't tried so not sure if closing the cursors in the array  would affect the MergeCursor, probably best to assume so and close all when done).

[MergeCursor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MergeCursor.html)

---

### Working Example :-

The invoking activity **MainActivity.java** :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper dbhlpr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dbhlpr = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        dbhlpr.populateQuestions(500,6);
        Cursor questions = dbhlpr.getRandomQuestionsForBanks(new int[]{1,3},5);

        while (questions.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d("QUESTIONS",
                    "ID=" +   questions.getLong(questions.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.QUESTION_ID_COL)) +
                    " BANK=" + questions.getInt(questions.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.QUESTION_BANK_ID))+
                    " QUESTION=" + questions.getString(questions.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.QUESTION_QUESTION))
            );
        }
        questions.close();
    }
}
```

The Database helper **Databasehelper.java**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "questionsdb";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;
    public static final String QUESTIONS_TBNAME = "questions";
    public static final String QUESTION_ID_COL = "question_id";
    public static final String QUESTION_BANK_ID = "question_bank_id";
    public static final String QUESTION_QUESTION = "question_question";

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;
    static Random r;

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME,null,DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String questions_crtsql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOt EXISTS " + QUESTIONS_TBNAME +
                "(" +
                QUESTION_ID_COL + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                QUESTION_BANK_ID + " INTEGER, " +
                QUESTION_QUESTION + " TEXT" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(questions_crtsql);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public void populateQuestions(int rowstoadd, int numberofbanks) {
        final String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

        Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        if (DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(mDB,QUESTIONS_TBNAME) < 1) {
            mDB.beginTransaction();
            for (int i = 0; i < rowstoadd; i++) {
                int aix = r.nextInt(alphabet.length());
                int bank = r.nextInt(numberofbanks) + 1;
                cv.clear();
                cv.put(QUESTION_BANK_ID,bank);
                cv.put(QUESTION_QUESTION,alphabet.substring(aix,aix+1));

                mDB.insert(QUESTIONS_TBNAME,null,cv);
            }
            mDB.setTransactionSuccessful();
            mDB.endTransaction();
            Log.d("POPULATE","Number of rows in table after populate is" + DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(mDB,QUESTIONS_TBNAME));
        } else {
            Log.d("POPULATE","Number of rows in table is" + DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(mDB,QUESTIONS_TBNAME));
        }
    }
    
    public Cursor getRandomQuestionsPerBank(int bank, int numbertoget) {
        return  mDB.query(
                QUESTIONS_TBNAME,
                new String[]{QUESTION_ID_COL, QUESTION_QUESTION, QUESTION_BANK_ID},
                QUESTION_BANK_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{Integer.toString(bank)},
                null, null," random()",
                Integer.toString(numbertoget)
        );
    }

    public Cursor getRandomQuestionsForBanks(int[] banklist, int numbertoget) {
        Cursor[] cursors = new Cursor[banklist.length];
        for (int i=0; i < banklist.length; i++) {
            cursors[i] = getRandomQuestionsPerBank(banklist[i],numbertoget);
        }
        return new MergeCursor(cursors);
    }
}
```

Example Output  from 3 runs being :-

```
12-27 07:19:22.747 2370-2370/? D/POPULATE: Number of rows in table after populate is500
12-27 07:19:22.748 2370-2370/? D/QUESTIONS: ID=414 BANK=1 QUESTION=I
12-27 07:19:22.748 2370-2370/? D/QUESTIONS: ID=215 BANK=1 QUESTION=P
12-27 07:19:22.748 2370-2370/? D/QUESTIONS: ID=336 BANK=1 QUESTION=L
12-27 07:19:22.748 2370-2370/? D/QUESTIONS: ID=243 BANK=1 QUESTION=M
12-27 07:19:22.748 2370-2370/? D/QUESTIONS: ID=226 BANK=1 QUESTION=H
12-27 07:19:22.748 2370-2370/? D/QUESTIONS: ID=376 BANK=3 QUESTION=Y
12-27 07:19:22.748 2370-2370/? D/QUESTIONS: ID=282 BANK=3 QUESTION=M
12-27 07:19:22.748 2370-2370/? D/QUESTIONS: ID=113 BANK=3 QUESTION=M
12-27 07:19:22.748 2370-2370/? D/QUESTIONS: ID=80 BANK=3 QUESTION=O
12-27 07:19:22.748 2370-2370/? D/QUESTIONS: ID=413 BANK=3 QUESTION=D

12-27 07:23:29.502 2561-2561/? D/POPULATE: Number of rows in table is500
12-27 07:23:29.503 2561-2561/? D/QUESTIONS: ID=226 BANK=1 QUESTION=H
12-27 07:23:29.503 2561-2561/? D/QUESTIONS: ID=414 BANK=1 QUESTION=I
12-27 07:23:29.503 2561-2561/? D/QUESTIONS: ID=124 BANK=1 QUESTION=A
12-27 07:23:29.503 2561-2561/? D/QUESTIONS: ID=128 BANK=1 QUESTION=I
12-27 07:23:29.503 2561-2561/? D/QUESTIONS: ID=379 BANK=1 QUESTION=U
12-27 07:23:29.503 2561-2561/? D/QUESTIONS: ID=282 BANK=3 QUESTION=M
12-27 07:23:29.504 2561-2561/? D/QUESTIONS: ID=275 BANK=3 QUESTION=Z
12-27 07:23:29.504 2561-2561/? D/QUESTIONS: ID=371 BANK=3 QUESTION=C
12-27 07:23:29.504 2561-2561/? D/QUESTIONS: ID=106 BANK=3 QUESTION=M
12-27 07:23:29.504 2561-2561/? D/QUESTIONS: ID=35 BANK=3 QUESTION=B

12-27 07:24:06.794 2621-2621/mjt.questionsmergecursor D/POPULATE: Number of rows in table is500
12-27 07:24:06.795 2621-2621/mjt.questionsmergecursor D/QUESTIONS: ID=292 BANK=1 QUESTION=B
12-27 07:24:06.795 2621-2621/mjt.questionsmergecursor D/QUESTIONS: ID=201 BANK=1 QUESTION=F
12-27 07:24:06.795 2621-2621/mjt.questionsmergecursor D/QUESTIONS: ID=384 BANK=1 QUESTION=I
12-27 07:24:06.795 2621-2621/mjt.questionsmergecursor D/QUESTIONS: ID=305 BANK=1 QUESTION=M
12-27 07:24:06.796 2621-2621/mjt.questionsmergecursor D/QUESTIONS: ID=50 BANK=1 QUESTION=S
12-27 07:24:06.796 2621-2621/mjt.questionsmergecursor D/QUESTIONS: ID=295 BANK=3 QUESTION=U
12-27 07:24:06.796 2621-2621/mjt.questionsmergecursor D/QUESTIONS: ID=66 BANK=3 QUESTION=Z
12-27 07:24:06.796 2621-2621/mjt.questionsmergecursor D/QUESTIONS: ID=290 BANK=3 QUESTION=F
12-27 07:24:06.796 2621-2621/mjt.questionsmergecursor D/QUESTIONS: ID=91 BANK=3 QUESTION=O
12-27 07:24:06.796 2621-2621/mjt.questionsmergecursor D/QUESTIONS: ID=433 BANK=3 QUESTION=S
```

Note! I tested closing the array Cursors, you can't as you get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object`. So code should facilitate closing the array cursors.

Comment: Thanks man. It is really helpful for sqlite. Currently I am using Room persistence library. But I can really take help from your code. I will use the random query in a loop. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

You could use `IN`. Like `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE ID IN (1,2,3,4,5);`

Comment: I need items by position not by their id.

Answer (score -2):

**Way 1:**

You can use following query to achieve this:

```
Select * from your_table_name where rowid in (1,5,6,10,15);
```

Here, in the brackets `(1,5,6,10,15)`, you will pass positions from your array of positions.

**Way 2: (Preferable for small amount of data)**

Fetch all records from this table into one List and fetch items from this List for the desired positions, if **Way 1** does't fit your requirement.

Comment: I do not know the rowid. It can be anything. I need the rows according to their positions. rowid is not position of the row.

Answer (score -2):

Use IN statement of sql like this:

> SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name WHERE positions IN (1, 2, ...);

Comment: I have no column as positions. Positions are not IDs.